# Private Link Service Connection - Find my instance GroupID

Tags: sql-server, azure, networking

***How do i retrieve the Group-ID of SQL-Server within Azure ?***

I want to use the preview technology of "Private Endpoint Connection". To 
do this i need to configure an group-id when adding SQL-Server as target.

The document describes the group-id as: "The ID(s) of the group(s) obtained from the remote resource that this private endpoint should connect to."

I tried the MSDN page, found the test-scripts of MSFT (MyronFanQiu) that create a Loadbalancer and started to adjust them.
Found that the subnet i was using had to be cleared of network-policies.

> Requires Az 2.0.72 to work.

```
  az login
    az account set --subscription $subscriptionid

#Clean the subnet    
    az network vnet subnet update -g $rg -n $subnet1 --vnet-name $vnet --disable-private-endpoint-network-policies --disable-private-link-service-network-policies --verbose  

#Create the link-services
    $pls1 = az network private-link-service create -g $rg -n $lks1 --vnet-name $vnet --subnet $subnet1 --lb-name $lb --lb-frontend-ip-configs LoadBalancerFrontEnd -l $location      
    az network private-endpoint create -g $rg -n $pe --vnet-name $vnet --subnet $subnet1 --private-connection-resource-id $ResourceID --connection-name tttt -l $location --group-id $ResourceID
    az network private-endpoint update -g $rg -n $pe --request-message "Accept please"
    az network private-endpoint list
#Clean up  
    az network private-link-service delete --ids /subscriptions/$($subscriptionid)/resourceGroups/$($rg)/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateLinkServices/$lks1
    az network private-link-service list
```

ERROR: IncorrectPrivateLinkServiceConnectionGroupId - Private Link Service Connection Group Id is incorrect for Azure SQL DB
az : This command group is in preview. It may be changed/removed in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

Preview - its not possible (yet) as the PowerShell's commands are missing:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/10505

for the documentation; please review https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/private-link-service?view=azure-cli-latest.